# Angular 8 how to pass current object and its index in change event

Tags: angular8

```
    <pre>
    <select (change)="getSelecteItem()">
      <option *ngFor="let item of sampleDropDown">
        {{item.value}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <pre>

public sampleDropDown =
    [{ id: '1', value: 'Test0' }, { id: '2', value: 'Test1' }, { id: '1', value: 'Test2' }];

  getSelecteItem() {

  }
</code>
```

I am binding dropdown using Angular 8 with *ngFor.. 
1) I want to pass current selected option in change event
2) I want to pass current selected option index in change event

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by accessing the special variable `$event`.

In your template (HTML file)

```
<select (change)="getSelecteItem($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of sampleDropDown">
    {{ item.value }}
  </option>
</select>
```

In your component:

```
  getSelecteItem(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value); //// test0, test1, etc...
  }
```

Comment: event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex
event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex].text
event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex].value

Answer (score 0):

```
<select (change)="getSelecteItem($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of sampleDropDown" value="{{item.id}}" >
    {{item.value}}
  </option>
</select>

  public sampleDropDown =
    [{ id: '1', value: 'Test0' }, { id: '2', value: 'Test1' }, { id: '1', value: 'Test2' }];


 getSelecteItem(event) {
    event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex
    event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex].text
    event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex].value 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of an object with `*ngFor` and assign the index to the value of the select option. When the event is passed to the change function the index can be used in the `sampleDropDown` array.

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->

<select (change)="getSelecteItem($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of sampleDropDown; index as i" value="{{i}}" >
    {{item.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

```js
  //app.component.ts

public sampleDropDown = [{ id: '1', value: 'Test0' }, { id: '2', value: 'Test1' }, { id: '1', value: 'Test2' }];
public selectedItem: any;
public selectedItemValue: any;

getSelecteItem(event) {
  let index = event.target.value;
  this.selectedItem = this.sampleDropDown[index];
  this.selectedItemValue = this.sampleDropDown[index].value;
}
```